# Trigger a script in another server

Tags: shell-script

I have a script which in turn triggers 4 more scripts in another server sequentially. My script is waiting until the first script completes in target server and then triggers the second one. Below is the code

```
SCB_CMD=/sc/db2home/scbinst/bin/reload_scrpt1.sh
SCB_LOG=/sc/db2home/scbinst/log/reload_scrpt1.log

echo `date` "Executing $SCB_HOST:$SCB_CMD ..." 

ssh $SCB_HOST "$SCB_CMD | tee $SCB_LOG"

RC=$?

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Check for errors
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
if [ $RC -ne 0 ]
then
  echo `date` "!error occurred executing SCB load script1!" 

  exit 99
fi
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SCB_CMD=/sc/db2home/scbinst/bin/reload_scrpt2.sh
SCB_LOG=/sc/db2home/scbinst/log/reload_scrpt2.log

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- Execute the remote load script
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo `date` "Executing $SCB_HOST:$SCB_CMD ..." 

ssh $SCB_HOST "$SCB_CMD | tee $SCB_LOG"
--------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to trigger all these four scripts in parallel in target server?

Answer (score 1):

`&` at the end of a command puts the job in background.

I'd rewrite my script

connector.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo `date` "Executing $1:$2"
# 1 host, 2 cmd, 3 log
ssh $1 "$2 | tee $3"
```

add the runner.sh script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
connector.sh 127.0.0.1 /sc/db2home/scbinst/bin/reload_scrpt1.sh /var/log.log &

connector.sh 127.0.0.1 /sc/db2home/scbinst/bin/reload_scrpt2.sh /var/log.log &

connector.sh 127.0.0.1 /sc/db2home/scbinst/bin/reload_scrpt3.sh /var/log.log &
```

Comment: Make `connector` a function in `runner.sh`. There's no need for a separate script.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the jobs in parallel (I assuming the `ssh` commands work on the command line had you run them individually, meaning, it's not any issue with the remote vis-a-vis local m/c issue.

```
for i in `seq 1 4`; do
   SCB_CMD=/sc/db2home/scbinst/bin/reload_scrpt${i}.sh
   SCB_LOG=/sc/db2home/scbinst/log/reload_scrpt${i}.log

   echo `date` "Launching $SCB_HOST:$SCB_CMD ..."
   ssh "$SCB_HOST" "$SCB_CMD | tee $SCB_LOG" &

   sleep 1
done
```